# Change bluetooth device type from headphones to speaker?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, big-sur, speakers

When I'm connecting my bluetooth speakers to my iMac they connect as headphones. This leads to a restricted volume which I can't get around either.

For instance on iOS the option to change the bluetooth device type exists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  you have 3 sources that can control the volume:

1. Your System's Sound
2. The app you are using
3. Your Bluetooth speaker

What I usually do is turn down the level of the system's sound to 0 and crank up the volume of my speaker to the maximum.

If you goto to **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Output**, then choose your speaker if it is not selected and turn down the output volume.

Next, crank up the volume of your Bluetooth speaker on the speaker itself. Then set the volume of the source application you want to listen to, say Spotify, and increase the system's sound.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Thanks for the reminder. Although I was aware of this, I checked all three settings again and set them to maximum volume.
I still have the feeling, that the speakers are less loud compared to them connected to my iPad. But it's better now for sure. :)